# Where does yum save the RPM files it downloads?

Tags: yum, rpm

Is there a temporary folder I can find the RPM's that yum downloads to install programs? During an installation yum shows the exact name of the RPM file but I don't know how to find it. How can I search for the RPM if I know the name of it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `/var/cache/yum/<repo>/packages`.  This directory is expunged during package cleanup.

You can search for a file by name with the `find` command.  An example: `find / -name 'package.rpm'`  Wildcards are supported. `find -name 'package*.rpm'`

Comment: `/var/cache/yum` is a configurable location.  You need to check main.cachedir in `/etc/yum.conf`

Comment: I had to first enable `keepcache=1` in `/etc/yum.conf` as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79458/227037.

Answer (score 3):

I verified today that on RHEL 6.7, the files are stored in `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/rhel-6-server-rpms/packages/`.

It is also worth noting that the plugin `downloadonly` is included in RHEL 6:

```
# yum install yum-downloadonly
Package yum-plugin-downloadonly-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch is obsoleted by yum-3.2.29-69.el6.noarch which is already installed
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found it here:

`/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/rhel-7-server-rpms/packages`

Comment: This is a very solid reiteration of the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

It found in below location here x86_64 if for 64 bit centos/RHEL OS. It exist at location as package.rpm.tmp 
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/ 
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/

Answer (score 0):

The location of the cache is configurable, and although the default is `/var/cache/yum/`, it's much more reliable to check the value of main.cachedir in `/etc/yum.conf`.